Pandas dataframe reshape with columns name
I have a dataframe like this:
>>> df
  TYPE    A    B    C    D
0   IN  550  350  600  360
1  OUT  340  270  420  190

I want reshape it to this shape:
       AIN AOUT  BIN BOUT  CIN COUT  DIN DOUT
       550  340  350  270  600  420  360  190

So I use these codes to do it:
ds = df.melt().T.iloc[1:,2:]
ds.columns = ['AIN','AOUT','BIN','BOUT','CIN','COUT','DIN','DOUT']
>>> ds
       AIN AOUT  BIN BOUT  CIN COUT  DIN DOUT
value  550  340  350  270  600  420  360  190

It works, but it seems stupid, the columns name was manual inputed, I wonder if there's a better way more pythonic to do this. Any idea?
P.S. the "value" in output dataframe is insignificant.

Come on, The post you directed me to is completely different from the content of my post. :( I need combine columns name and vertical content to new column name, and I feel the "melt.T" is not pythonic way to solve my question.

Voted to reopen. Indeed, not at all clear how the suggested duplicate answers OP's question.

This question is similar to: How can I pivot a dataframe?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Starship-On Discussions Strike It looks like applying the pivot function is the best approach, as Panda Kim gave in the answer.

Code
Apply join function(python) with map function(pandas) to Multi-index.
out = df.assign(index=0).pivot(index='index', columns='TYPE')
out.columns = out.columns.map(''.join)

out:
       AIN  AOUT  BIN  BOUT  CIN  COUT  DIN  DOUT
index                                            
0      550   340  350   270  600   420  360   190

I chose pivot function because it is inconvenient when creating a 1-row dataframe because both melt and stack require T. (If I were creating a series or 1-column dataframe, I would have chosen melt or stack.)
Example Code
import pandas as pd
data = {'TYPE': ['IN', 'OUT'], 
        'A': [550, 340],
        'B': [350, 270],
        'C': [600, 420],
        'D': [360, 190]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


A possible solution, whose steps are:

The drop method removes the TYPE column from the dataframe df, resulting in a new dataframe.

The values method extracts the underlying numpy array from the modified dataframe.

The reshape method reshapes the array into a 2D array with one row and the same number of columns as the original dataframe.

The columns parameter is set to a list of strings generated by a list comprehension. Each string is a concatenation of a column name from df and a value from the TYPE column.

Finally, a new dataframe is created with the reshaped array and the new column names.


pd.DataFrame(
    df.drop('TYPE', axis=1).values.reshape(1,-1, order='A'),
    columns=[f'{x}{y}' for x in df.columns[1:] for y in df['TYPE']],
    index=['value'])

Output:
       AIN  AOUT  BIN  BOUT  CIN  COUT  DIN  DOUT
value  550   340  350   270  600   420  360   190



df.columns[1:] loop through the columns A, B, C, D, excluding the TYPE column.

The loop uses loc to filter the rows by TYPE and then extracts the corresponding values for each column.

And then new columns are constructed by combining the variable name (e.g., A, B, etc.) with IN and OUT suffixes.
for col in df.columns[1:]:
     reshaped_df[f'{col}IN'] = df.loc[df['TYPE'] == 'IN', col].values
     reshaped_df[f'{col}OUT'] = df.loc[df['TYPE'] == 'OUT', col].values



Output
   AIN  AOUT  BIN  BOUT  CIN  COUT  DIN  DOUT
0  550   340  350   270  600   420  360   190

